# Unable to update git history, all refs are unchanged

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm attempting to re-write some git history using the script below, slightly modified from [this blog](https://blog.tinned-software.net/rewrite-author-of-entire-git-repository/), which updates emails. I initially wanted to be more secure and decided to enable `Block command line pushes that expose my email` on GitHub, but realized my contribution graph was no longer updating.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Taken from https://blog.tinned-software.net/rewrite-author-of-entire-git-repository/
if [[ $# -eq 3 ]]; then
   git filter-branch -f --env-filter "
      if [ '$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL' = '$1' ]; then
         export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='$2'
         export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='$3'
      fi
      if [ '$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL' = '$1' ]; then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='$2'
         export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='$3'
      fi
      " --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
else
   echo "usage: $0 OLD_EMAIL NEW_EMAIL NEW_NAME"
   echo ""
   echo "    OLD_EMAIL     The email address to be replaced in the commits"
   echo "    NEW_EMAIL     The new author email address to be used in the commit matching OLD_EMAIL"
   echo "    NEW_NAME      The name which should be used in the commit matching OLD_EMAIL"
fi
```

The script runs and I get no errors form bash, but git tells me that none of the refs have been modified.

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/branch1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branch1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
```

Why it lists `origin/master` more than once is beyond me, but this is otherwise all of the branches for this repo, meaning nothing got updated. I did run `git shortlog -sne --all` before and after to make sure. I've been unable to find any documentation on this error as it directly relates to git. Is there something missing in the script?

Comment: `WARNING: Ref is unchanged` means the script didn't change any commits. I suspect a problem with wrong quotes and parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3`. See the working scripts at https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758